# Pass value of form field from view to controller via ajax and populate a dropdown city list based on state selection

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a state and city dropdown lists. The city is going to populate when the state is selected. I am doing this using ajax. I have everything written, I feel like it should work, and it of course does not. The state dropdown list is pulled from a seperate class containing an enumerable list of all 50 US states. Where as the second dropdown list I have written in my controller with hopes that I could return the Json data to populate the city dropdown.
Here is my razor for the dropdownlistfor's along with my jquery and ajax:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, WebGridProject.Models.StateCodes.GetStatesList(), new { id = "State", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "FillCity2()" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            function FillCity2() {
                var stateId = $('#State').val();
                console.log(stateId);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/FillCity2',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { State: stateId },
                    success: function (city) { // cities is the variable in the controller made to fetch the city list
                        $("#City").html(""); 
                        $.each(city, function (i , cityNames) {
                            $("#City").append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(cityNames.cities));
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()), "Select City", new { id = "City", @class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the controller action I am using to process the request:

```
public JsonResult FillCity2(string stateName)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> cities = new List<SelectListItem>();

            switch (stateName)
            {
                case "AK":
                    cities = new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "", Value = ""},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Anchorage", Value = "Anchorage"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Fairbanks", Value = "Fairbanks"},
                    };
                    break;
                case "AL":
                    cities = new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "", Value = ""},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Auburn", Value = "Auburn"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Birmingham", Value = "Birmingham"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Dothan", Value = "Dothan"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Mobile", Value = "Mobile"},
                    };
                    break;
                case "AZ":
                    cities = new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "", Value = ""},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Pheonix", Value = "Pheonix"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Flagstaff", Value = "Flagstaff"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Prescott", Value = "Prescott"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Tucson", Value = "Tucson"},
                    };
                    break;
                case "AR":
                    cities = new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "", Value = ""},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Fayetteville", Value = "Fayetteville"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Fort smith", Value = "Fort smith"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Jonesboro", Value = "Jonesboro"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Texarkana", Value = "Texarkana"},
                    };
                    break;
                default:
                    cities = new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "", Value = ""},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Please Select State", Value = "Please Select State"},
                    };
                    break;
            }
            return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

When I run in debugger the value for #State is showing up as null, although in the console in chrome it shows the actual value (e.g. 'AL' for Alabama, 'AK' for alaska, etc...).

I cant quite figure out where my issue with passing in the value is. And the city list in the debugger just keeps going to the default switch case.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you update the question title to meaningful (related to the real problem) so that it helps future readers.

Comment: To repeat my comment on your last question - refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: I looked at it. Its quite a bit more than I am looking for. Also I was having some issues with making it work. I appreciate you showing it to me though.

Comment: It works in the fiddle - your just use the code in it! (and its not more than you need - its the minimum you need to make all parts work correctly)

Comment: I appreciate it man. I got it figured out. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action method parameter name and the ajax call data parameter name should match. Since your ajax call is sending the selected state value in a parameter called `State`, you should update your action method to have the same (or the other way)

```
public JsonResult FillCity2(string state)
{
   //use the state variable in your method now for switch statement
}
```

Also, Your action method returns an list of `SelectListItem`,which has a `Text` and `Value` property. So you should use either of those properties when building the city dropdown. But you are trying to access the `cities` property of each item in the list which does not exist.

And the last,thing, you need to set the `text` of the option as well along with the value. Because text is what the user see.

```
success: function (cityArray) { 
    $("#City").html("");
    $.each(cityArray, function (i, city) {
        $("#City").append(
            $('<option></option>').val(city.Value).text(city.Text));
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what you mean with using the text or value property in my action?

Comment: Thank you! I dont have the list populating yet but the values are being loaded and retrieved in the controller action. #State value is being passed in and when I check the return statement, the value and text are no longer showing no. So I really appreciate your help. Hopefully I can figure this out soon.

Comment: Your action method returns an list of `SelectListItem` objects, each of which has a `Text` and `Value` property. So in your ajax call's success event, when you get this result (list of SelectListItem), you need to loop through that, read the Text property of the item to set the option text and read the Value property of the item to set the option value. (That is what this line of code does `$('<option></option>').val(city.Value).text(city.Text));`)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your ajax call should be using

```
data: { stateName: stateId },
```

instead of

```
data: { State: stateId },
```

to match the parameter name in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Do `console.log(city)` and look at its format. I suspect you're accessing the properties incorrectly. Also, I recommend using the native `add()` method:

```
success: function (stateCities) {
    var cities = document.getElementById('City');
    while (cities.options.length) {
        cities.remove(0);
    }
    $.each(stateCities, function(i, city) {
        cities.add(new Option(city.Value, city.Text));// or whatever the correct properties are
    });
}
```